# R merge two data.frame by id and sub-id while changing column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, aggregate

I have two dataframes of this format.

df1:

```
id x y
1  2 3
2  4 5
3  6 7
4  8 9
5  1 1
```

df2:

```
id id2 v v2 
1  t  11 21
1  b  12 22
2  t  13 23
2  b  14 24
3  t  15 25 
3  b  16 26
4  b  17 27
```

Hence, sometimes, the id in main 'df' will appear twice (maximum) sometimes once, and sometimes not at all. The expected result would be:

df_merged:

```
id x y v.t v2.t v.b v2.b
1  2 3 11  21   12  22
2  4 5 13  23   24  24
3  6 7 15  25   16  26
4  8 9 NA  NA   17  27
5  1 1 NA  NA   NA  NA
```

I have used merge but due to the fact that id2 in df2 doesn't match, I get two instances of id in df_merged like so:

```
id x y v v2
1  ... 
1  ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start by adjusting `df2` to the right format then do a normal joining.

```
librar(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>% gather(key,val,-id,-id2) %>%   #Transfer from wide to long format for v and v2
        mutate(new_key=paste0(key,'.',id2)) %>%  #Create a new id2 as new_key
        select(-id2,-key) %>%     #de-select the unnessary columns
        spread(new_key,val) %>%   #Transfer back to wide foramt with right foramt for id
        right_join(df1) %>%       #right join df1 "To includes all rows in df1" using id
        select(id,x,y,v.t,v2.t,v.b,v2.b) #rearrange columns name
Joining, by = "id"
  id x y v.t v2.t v.b v2.b
1  1 2 3  11   21  12   22
2  2 4 5  13   23  14   24
3  3 6 7  15   25  16   26
4  4 8 9  NA   NA  17   27
5  5 1 1  NA   NA  NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this just using `merge`. Split `df2` based on whether `id2` equals `b` or `t`. Merge these two new objects with `df1`, and finally merge them together. The code includes one additional step to also include data found in `df1` but not `df2`.

```
dfb <- merge(df1, df2[df2$id2=='b',], by='id')
dft <- merge(df1, df2[df2$id2=='t',], by='id')
dfRest <- df1[!df1$id %in% df2$id,]
dfAll <- merge(dfb[,c('id','x','y','v','v2')], dft[,c('id','v','v2')], by='id', all.x=T)
merge(dfAll, dfRest, all.x=T, all.y=T)

  id x y v.x v2.x v.y v2.y
1  1 2 3  12   22  11   21
2  2 4 5  14   24  13   23
3  3 6 7  16   26  15   25
4  4 8 9  17   27  NA   NA
5  5 1 1  NA   NA  NA   NA
```